# Why does does the first term of a simulated MA(1) model with low variance have much larger absolute value than the rest?

Tags: r, time-series, moving-average

When doing some simulations in R to learn about moving average models I noticed something in the time series plots I could not explain. When I take the innovations/noise terms to be from a normal distribution of low variance, (less than 0.1) then the plots seem to start with a term which is much bigger than the rest in absolute value. After that, it has the behaviour I expected, i.e. some noise around the mean of $0$ with constant variance.

I have included a few plots that show what I mean and the code I used to generate them.

```
set.seed(5)
x1 = arima.sim(model = list(ma = 0.2), n = 100, innov=rnorm(100, 0, 0.01^2))
x2 = arima.sim(model = list(ma = 0.8), n = 100, innov=rnorm(100, 0, 0.01^2))
x3 = arima.sim(model = list(ma = 0.2), n = 100, innov=rnorm(100, 0, 0.1^2))
x4 = arima.sim(model = list(ma = 0.8), n = 100, innov=rnorm(100, 0, 0.1^2))
plot.ts(cbind(x1,x2,x3,x4))
```

[image: Plots]

I believe the model I am using is $$ m_t = a_t + \alpha a_{t-1}$$ where $\{a_t\}$ are white noise terms with mean zero and variance $0.1$ or $0.01$ and $\alpha$ is $0.2$ or $0.8$ which is the weight given to previous noise. An idea I have is that there is something different about the first term because there is no previous term to use in the model, but I can't see how that explains what I see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right that MA(1) simulation is an iterated process, and the iteration needs to start at something.

The starting value of iteration is defined by the `start.innov` parameter of `arima.sim`. In case of missing `start.innov`, `arima.sim` seems to use a random number generator to choose the initial value, and the random numbers seem to come from a distribution with a variance higher than 0.1^2. (I could not find the defaults but perhaps someone else knows this?)

You can manually set a0:

```
x1 = arima.sim(model = list(ma = 0.2), n = 100, innov=rnorm(100, 0, 0.01^2), start.innov=0)
```

Or in the case of stationary MA, you can just simulate a slightly longer time series so that it is not affected by the inital values:

```
 x1 = arima.sim(model = list(ma = 0.2), n = 130, innov=rnorm(130, 0, 0.01^2) )[31:130]
```

Comment: Knowing about the start.innov parameter makes it all make sense, and setting start.innov to $0$ gives me what I wanted to see. I guess I could figure out the default by doing print(arima.sim) and reading through the code but I'm not too concerned with what the default is for now. Thanks!